# Synonymize [pom] and [pom.xml] to [maven]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

The concept of a POM (Project Object Model), or the pom.xml file itself, *only* exists in Maven.  Most questions that include the [pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom.xml) tag also include [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven).  It makes little sense to keep these tags separate, since they refer to the same problem domain.

Of the [handful of questions which *only* have the pom.xml tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/722553), few of them are on-topic or should remain open, and a clean-up effort would be nice.

(I can't do this myself since [pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom) is a synonym of [pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom.xml).)

---

To address some concerns about whether or not this synonym makes sense, let me reiterate (as I don't want my earlier comments to be lost):

If a user posts a question with the tag [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven), they have a Maven question. This could be related to the command line interface, flags, or interop with plugins.

If a user posts a question today with the tag [pom.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom.xml), **they are still having a Maven problem**, albeit one much more narrow in scope.

I see the argument that "POMs beget Maven, but Maven doesn't necessarily beget POMs", but these two things are linked together.  A larger subset of Maven problems *includes* POMs, and you would be hard-pressed to find a professional in Maven that has no idea how to respond to a POM problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why we have a [porn] tag. Oh wait, dang kerning...

Comment: For those who are unfamiliar with maven/pom file. The Pom file is pretty much the main component of Maven, like as a SLN file for Visual Studio. The exception is the settings file for proxy and some other stuff. This means that most of the question about Maven (like 90%) will have the solution implemented in the Pom file. The rest is either abouit the setting or how to call a specific maven plugin in command line.

Comment: I would agree 100% with this, except that I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45615417) at some point. Indirectly, that is related to Maven, but, it's mostly about Gradle and POM. There [are more](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/722885).

Comment: `pom` stands for Project Object Model for those that might not know why it is called that.

Comment: @Justastudent:  I still fail to see how those aren't still a Maven problem.  To play devil's advocate, you weren't having a specific problem with Gradle; you were having a problem with your buildscript.  See what I'm getting at there? ;)

Answer (score 13):

I would keep them separate.

[maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) actually is proper for all `maven` related questions (including `mvn` command or maybe especially `mvn`) but `pom.xml` specifies that the problem relates to the `pom.xml` itself.

I think that it's kind of similar to [angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-cli) and [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) -> once the question relates `angular-cli` it also relates to `angular`.

Synonymization is bidirectional operation. I can agree to `pom -> maven` but does `maven -> pom`?

Comment: Having a problem with your POM *is* having a problem in Maven.

Comment: But not visa versa. Do these are not synonyms

Comment: If a person uses the [tag:maven] tag right now, they're having a Maven problem that isn't related to the POM.  If a person uses the [tag:pom.xml] tag, **they're still having a Maven problem**.  The directionality of this may be throwing you off a bit.

Comment: If someone asks about ArrayList they add Java tag as well, right?

Comment: ArrayLists exist in C# as well, so...no.

Comment: @Makoto if I ask about `ng-repeat` and add tag `ng-repeat` should I add angular? Or maybe we'd mark them as synonims?

Comment: Gotta admit I hate seeing tags like `ng-repeat` *without* `angularjs`.  Yes, it's an AngularJS-centric thing, but it's still a question about AngularJS, so yes...that'd be a viable synonym in my mind.

Comment: I got bored :p I'm off that conversation :D

Comment: So can I interpret this as you withdrawing your objection then?

Comment: I believe that both tags are useful, so I wouldn't synonimize them.

Answer (score 1):

I think there should be some distinction between [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) questions that are about the command line and do not have anything to do with the `pom.xml`. Those might be few, but they exist.

[pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom) or [pom-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom-xml) implicitly includes [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven)

[maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) does **not** implicitly include [pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom) or [pom-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pom-xml).

I do not know if the system allows non-reciprocal synonyms like that.

Either way I do not see a problem in the way it is now. If anything I would suggest adding a new [mvn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvn) to identify the command line only questions.

Comment: I'd argue that synonymizing [tag:pom] to [tag:maven] would catch the implicit includes, and the questions which *aren't* related to POMs and are *just* Maven questions wouldn't be impacted.  This is genuinely about bring the questions about Maven POMs back into the fold.

Comment: Additionally, mvn is already synonymized to [tag:maven], so at one point the community believed that "mvn" the command isn't that much different from "Maven".

Comment: Can you do one way synonyms?

Comment: I've never heard of one before.  I'm not really sure if it'd make sense in this context.