# When a user is asking a question with a certain tag, add the ability to prompt them with guidance

Tags: discussion, feature-request

This request stems from my observations of questions submitted with the [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) tag.  One of the most common type of question is "how do I locate the following element". In order to help answer this question, a copy of the user's web page's full HTML or a link to the web page in question is essential.  So I'd like it if we could add some warning when the selenium tag is added.  I found [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274632/help-the-helpless-with-how-to-ask-tag-tips) which adds a warning for the [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) tag. Is this still an available feature? I think it would be helpful to add something like this to the [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium) tag, along the lines of:

> If you are looking for help finding an element on a web page, please provide the full HTML for the page or the page's URL; this is the only way to ensure we find a unique selector for your element.

Here are some examples of what I am talking about:

[Result of xpath expression is object and should be element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55202994/result-of-xpath-expression-is-object-and-should-be-element)

[What is the proper Xpath for the given element for using in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55194753/what-is-the-proper-xpath-for-the-given-element-for-using-in-selenium)

[Unable to find the value(element) in Xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213874/unable-to-find-the-valueelement-in-xpath)

... there are many more examples I could provide if desired.

Is this possible and what would I need to do/who would I want to contact to accomplish this?

Comment: Good idea; I think this could be the next iteration of the Ask A Question Wizard, perhaps generated dynamically from information stored in the tag wiki.  We might have to enhance and/or formalize the tag wiki template. I'm thinking of something like FixML.

Comment: Is there anything I can do to help make that happen?

Comment: You already did. A few more examples, and extrapolating from that the common kinds of patterns we have to capture, would also be a big help

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by “common kinds of patterns we have to capture”.  Maybe I’m being dense here but if you could explain in more detail that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Asking to provide the URL to a page is not a good idea, as eventually that page will either change or become invalid, which would render the original problem as not being reproducible.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Ah I didn’t realize that question examples were required to be reproducible indefinitely and not just intended to answer the user’s question.  I don’t think that threshold is achieved with much regularity, at least on the tags I frequent.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf I’ve thought a bit more about your comment and I would contend that for selenium at least, even if the URL is not provided, such changes to or invalidation of web page would inherently render the problem as not reproducible in most cases. When using selenium to automate a browser one must use the browser.get(URL) method, meaning that any change to the web page that makes the issue unreproducible will do so regardless of whether the URL is provided. It is simply the nature of automated testing that web pages change, and tests regularly break due to such changes.

Comment: If a question depends on a website to show the issue, and if the change on the website making the question invalid, then the question is eligible to be closed as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced" though, and making the question worth less... so it's better to ask for the rendered HTML's source code (or, at least the structure of the page) instead.

Comment: I see what you mean.  As I mentioned earlier I didn’t realize questions were intended to be reproducible resources in perpetuity.  Especially regarding the types of questions I reference above I can hardly see anyone but the original asker benefiting from the question and its answer(s), and, for me at least, looking at the actual web page and inspecting the DOM is by far the fastest way to provide an answer. Anyway, I cede my point with the caveat that users very rarely respond correctly to a request to see the page’s source code.

Comment: CPeck: The entire purpose of the site is to build a knowledgebase of programming information. It's not to help an individual user - if it happens to do so while building that knowledgebase, that's great, but in order to be useful here it has to have value for future users. URLs to off-site locations as you're suggesting do not provide that value, as @Dijkgraaf explained. In addition, the [help/on-topic] says clearly that questions asking for debugging help must include the relevant code here in the question itself.

Comment: Related: [Allow community to vote to create and edit tag warnings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356830/215552), [Can we have tag warnings or full blocks for particular tag combinations?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306640/215552), [Help the helpless with how-to-ask tag tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274632/215552)

Comment: @KenWhite I was completely unaware of your first two sentences and thought it was basically the opposite.  Thanks for cluing me in!

Comment: Leaving aside the issue of URLs for selenium questions, I think this would be enormously useful in many tags. For example, I can't tell you how nice it would be if everyone posting a question with `[r]` was automatically told how to post their data in a reproducible way with `dput`